# Class function echos output inside heredoc string, but in wrong place

Tags: php, class, function, heredoc

I'm trying to use a heredoc string in one section of my script, and inside this heredoc string is a function from inside a class that inputs some dynamic bit of stuff.

The function outputs the code correctly... but in the wrong place. Here's what I mean:

```
$output = <<<HTML
blah blah
blah
blah blah
<select>
{$admin->dropAcctNumbers()}
</select>
blah blah
blah
HTML;
```

When this is displayed in the web browser, it shows the code echo'd from inside the `dropAcctNumbers()` all the way up here:

```
    <option>Account Numbers</option>
blah blah
blah
blah blah
<select>
</select>
blah blah
blah
```

When it should be here:

```
blah blah
blah
blah blah
<select>
    <option>Account Numbers</option>
</select>
blah blah
blah
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method `$admin->dropAcctNumbers` is printing information instead of `returning` it ..

Example

```
echo "<pre>";
$admin = function () {
    print "    Account Numbers";
};

$output = <<<HTML
blah blah
blah
blah blah
{$admin()}
blah blah
blah
HTML;

echo $output;
```

Output

```
    Account Numbersblah blah
blah
blah blah

blah blah
blah
```

And

```
echo "<pre>";
$admin = function () {  return "    Account Numbers" ; } ;

$output = <<<HTML
blah blah
blah
blah blah
{$admin()}
blah blah
blah
HTML;

echo $output ;
```

Output

```
blah blah
blah
blah blah
    Account Numbers
blah blah
blah
```

Comment: I'm not sure I want the `<pre>` tag... I modified my example slightly to reflect what's actually going on.

Comment: The two cases ... are 100% different ... but they would still give different result See Print : http://codepad.viper-7.com/XU01jm  and See Return : http://codepad.viper-7.com/U4Ni0q

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
echo "<pre>".$output."</pre>";
```

Comment: I'm not sure I want the `<pre>` tag... I modified my example slightly to reflect what's actually going on.